# Failed to configure network bonding on CentOS 7 with Ansible

Tags: centos, linux-networking, ansible, bonding

I am trying to configure a bond interface using the Ansible `net_linkagg` module but the tasks failed with the following error.

`FAILED! => {"msg": "ansible_network_os must be specified on this host to use platform agnostic modules"}`

I have looked up in the module documentation but there is no value for the `ansible_network_os` variable that matches CentOS.

```
  - name: Configure Bonding Interfaces (Private Network)
    net_linkagg:
        name: bond1
        members: 
         - "{{ bond1Iface01 }}"
         - "{{ bond1Iface02 }}"
        purge: false
        state: up
        mode: active
```

How can I create the bonding interface for CentOS using Ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"How can I create the bonding interface for CentOS using Ansible?"*

A: Use [nmcli – Manage Networking](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/nmcli_module.html#nmcli-manage-networking) Ansible module.

---

Notes

- Module [net_linkagg](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/net_linkagg_module.html#net-linkagg-manage-link-aggregation-groups-on-network-devices) "*is supported on ansible_network_os network platforms. See the [Network Platform Options](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_index.html#platform-options) for details"*.